# Selenium (C#) IEWebDriver Use ExecuteJavaScript calling jQuery to return an IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to this but I want to attempt something like this:

```
var clickableThing = myWebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<IWebElement>("return $('" + Selector + "');");
clickableThing.Click();
```

My aim is to bypass the IE driver's css selector and use an alternative css selection implementation.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How doesn't that work? What errors are you getting? (It should work fine, on the face of it)

Comment: I have to wonder what part of "the IE driver's css selector[sic]" you're trying to bypass. With the exception of very old, legacy versions of IE, the driver uses the browser's native CSS selector engine, essentially calling `document.querySelector()` under the covers. In the cases of versions of IE that do not support CSS selectors, it uses the Sizzle CSS selector engine anyway, which jQuery also uses.

Comment: I have a situation where the IE css selector timed out for a few of  my calls. This does not happen with the Sizzle/jQuery alternative that Troy Gizzi helped me develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to return a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

If so, then adding `[0]` should do the trick:

```
var clickableThing = myWebDriver.ExecuteJavaScript<IWebElement>("return $('" + Selector + "')[0];");
clickableThing.Click();
```

**Follow-Up Verification**

*Disclaimer: This may not apply to you, since I'm apparently using a different version of the WebDriver (mine has the `ExecuteScript` method, not `ExecuteJavaScript`). But just as a sanity check...*

I have a little C# helper library for Selenium, which had the following Click method:

```
public void Click(string cssSelector)
{
    Log("Clicking element \"{0}\".", cssSelector.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
    _driver.FindElementByCssSelector(cssSelector).Click();
}
```

When I updated it to use the JavaScript approach from your original post, it threw an exception because it couldn't cast the return object to an `IWebElement`.

```
public void Click(string cssSelector)
{
    Log("Clicking element \"{0}\".", cssSelector.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
    IWebElement webElement = (IWebElement)_driver.ExecuteScript("return $('" + cssSelector + "');");
    webElement.Click();
}
```

But when I added the `[0]`, it worked.

```
public void Click(string cssSelector)
{
    Log("Clicking element \"{0}\".", cssSelector.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
    IWebElement webElement = (IWebElement)_driver.ExecuteScript("return $('" + cssSelector + "')[0];");
    webElement.Click();
}
```

So, while this isn't targeting the exact same `IJavaScriptExecutor` interface implementation, I think it at least indicates that the `[0]` tweak will probably fix things.

Comment: I'm still getting `Script returned a value, but the result could not be cast to the desired type`

Comment: Can you try running it with `<object>` instead of `<IWebElement>`, and then inspect the return value to see what it's actually returning?

Comment: Cast happens before assignment, hence exception before value is returned. No idea what ExecuteJavaScript's internal type is.

Comment: Okay, I just did a little research. I think the problem is with the `ExecuteJavaScript` extension method. I implemented what I found at the bottom of [this page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/support/Extensions/WebDriverExtensions.cs?spec=svn3a99cb332fb749f89ae3c8ca7126c9a5de12a8b0&r=3a99cb332fb749f89ae3c8ca7126c9a5de12a8b0), and modified my code to use that. It failed because `result.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` returns false. But I can in fact cast `result` to an `IWebElement`. So, bottom line, use `ExecuteScript()` directly instead.

Comment: This works, but it is not perfect. The logs from the selenium standalone server now reports "unknown locator" for it's "is displayed" calls. It is not an issue as the solution works, but it does show the cast is a bit more involved than I initially thought.